# Достаточно ли использование SSL для шифрации сообщений?

Tags: ssl, безопасность, криптография, клиент-сервер

Добрый день, у меня возник вопрос, в котором не могу разобраться, поэтому, объясните, если не сложно.

Хочется организовать безопасный обмен сообщениями между клиентом (браузер) и сервером. Понимаю, что SSL в этом поможет, но не понимаю, достаточно ли этого? Нужно ли дополнительно шифровать сами сообщения (парами ключей, например)?

Если SSL шифрует трафик, то для чего выпускают всякие якобы защищенные чаты и хвастаются, какое крутое шифрование у них используется?

Comment: > Если SSL шифрует трафик, то для чего выпускают всякие якобы защищенные чаты и хвастаются, какое крутое шифрование у них используется?

1. SSL, насколько помню, сам по себе подвержен MitM-атакам
2. Иногда требуется всякая веселуха типа encrypt-then-mac, что невозможно, если у тебя интерфейс вообще "не видит" шифрования
3. Защищенные чаты обычно используют то же AES-шифрование, что и SSL, с этой т.з. разницы никакой
4. Защищенные чаты зачастую и хранят все в зашифрованном виде, что к SSL просто не имеет никакого отношения
5. Это модно

Comment: А, ну еще таким образом чатики добиваются того, что на каждое сообщение может генерироваться свой собственный ключ. Насколько понимаю, SSL устанавливает ключ единожды за подключение. Теоретически повторное использование ключа может позволить злоумышленнику хотя бы частично разгадать его (едва ли не все популярное шифрование упирается в банальный xor), но я не слышал о том, чтобы OpenSSL взламывали таким способом (я так понимаю, регенерация ключа по тем или иным причинам происходит быстрее необходимости повторного использования).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципе, нормально настроенного ssl хватит. Но как всегда, проблема в третьей стороне. Дело в том, что возможна атака Men-In-Middle - когда на самом деле к сайту обращаетесь не напрямую, а через специальную прокси. На прокси стоит подложный сертификат, что дает возможность расшифровывать сообщения. При правильной организации, ни сервер, ни клиент не узнает о подлоге. Почему так? А все дело в том, что клиент не может просто так проверить, что сертификат именного того, кто предоставляет сервис. Поэтому, он обращается к центрам сертификации. А вот они могут быть вломаны/куплены/окружены паяльниками.

Добавление своего встроенного шифрования немного может помочь, если сделать все правильно, но стоит ли Ваша информация того, что бы ее так защищать?

Многие чаты позволяют сверить fingerpring - отпечаток ключа и тем самым убедиться своими глазами, что сертификат соответствует тому, кому он ожидает.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже говорили выше, атака Men-In-The-Middle - это та самая опасность, которая может поджидать вас. Скачайте, например, программу Fiddler 2, установите на свой компьютер - и вуаля! Если вы используете Chrome, то он даже не предупредит вас о том, что ваш трафик проходит через кого-то ещё. Mozila Firefox в этом плане более надёжный браузер. А Fiddler 2 именно так и работает - выдаёт сертификаты страниц за свои и перехватывает абсолютно весь ваш входящий и выходящий трафик. И не важно, что у вас стоит http или https. Для увеличения надёжности обычно шифруют сообщения, которые хотят передать, с помощью симметричного блокового шифрования на клиенте, а по сети уже передают используя шифрование ssl (ассиметричные системы шифрования). Если вы хотите написать действительно надёжную систему, лучше использовать дополнительное шифрование.